# Ordinal for day of the week

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to format the date like below

```
Tuesday, 2nd day of the week
```

So, far I have done

```
console.log(moment().format("dddd, Eo [day of the week]"))
```

Cannot add 'Eo' to get ordinal. It does not format 'o', print as `Sunday, 7o day of the week`

How can I get this done.

Comment: You should use `Do` replacing `Eo`.

Comment: @ashiish.me isn't `Do` for day for day of the month? I want day of the week

Comment: Aahh, I understand now, you just want 1st to 6th?

Comment: You can check the updated answer, it was supposed to be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Use `do` all small so that it returns all the ordinal from 0th to 6th.

```js
console.log(moment().format("dddd, do [day of the week]"))
```

Also, `E` returns Day of week without ordinal.

Update:

It seems with `do` I think the solution is still not applicable because of `0th` rather than `1st`.

Here's the custom implementation that can customize the date.

```js
const customizedDayWithOrdinal = input => {
  const [dayName, day] = input.split(',');
  const number = Number(day.trim()) % 10;

  const ordinal = (~~ (number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
            (number === 1) ? 'st' :
            (number === 2) ? 'nd' :
            (number === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
  return `${dayName}, ${number}${ordinal} of the week`;
}

console.log(customizedDayWithOrdinal(moment().format(`dddd, E`)))
```

The snippet is from the example of `moment.js` doc.

Reference: [Customize Ordinal](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/ordinal/)

Answer (score 1):

The format which moment is using is do.
You can have a look at the documentation

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

MomentJs doesn't provide the format of Eo, only Do. But you can still append the ordinal using your own function like so:

```
    const addOrdinal = (num) => {
        switch(num){
            case 1:
                return num + 'st'
            break
            case 2:
                return num + 'nd'
            break
            case 3:
                return num + 'rd'
            break
            default:
                return num + 'th'
        }
    }

    const day = moment().format(`dddd`)
    const dayOfWeek = addOrdinal(moment().format('E'))

    console.log(`${day}, ${dayOfWeek} day of the week `)
```

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/isaacyong/pen/NWbQXay)